# custom htaccess rewrite rule for page

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, htaccess, slug

i have a page in wordpress called "video". its page id is 6, and its slug is "video"

in my theme ive set it up to show content based on GET variables

here is the URL rewrite im trying to set up:

heres the original URL with the GET variables inside:

mysite.com/video/?video_id=102230&video_title=FC+Emmen+v+AGOVV+Apeldoorn&video_src=MTAyMjMw

heres the URL i want it rewritten to so it can be indexed:

mysite.com/video/102230/MTAyMjMw/FC+Emmen+v+AGOVV+Apeldoorn

heres my htaccess file that is not working:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^video/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ ?page_id=6&7video_id=$1&video_src=$2&video_title=$3 [NC]
</ifmodule>
# END WordPress
```

what happens is, when i try and visit mysite.com/video/102230/MTAyMjMw/FC+Emmen+v+AGOVV+Apeldoorn, it simply automatically goes to mysite.com/video and removes everything after /video

edit - now it is not removing everything after /video, but its telling me "Nothing found for  Video 102230 MTAyMjMw FC+Emmen+v+AGOVV+Apeldoorn"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with WordPress' built-in rewrite system.

```
function add_video_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_tag("%video_id%", '([^/]*)');
    add_rewrite_tag("%video_src%", '([^/]*)');
    add_rewrite_tag("%video_title%", '([^/]*)');
    add_rewrite_rule('^video/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/[^/]*)', 'index.php?pagename=video&video_id=$matches[1]&video_src=$matches[2]&video_title=$matches[3]', 'top');
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_video_rewrite' );
```

Didn't test it, but I think this should work.
What is does is first adding tags that you can use in your template (get_query_var(video_id)). Then add a rewriterule that specifically matches the URL.

You should put this code in your functions.php and then flush your rewriterules (go to setting > permalinks).

More info about rewriterules for WordPress:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API
http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag
http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

Comment: ok its not giving me the "page not found" anymore, however when i do print_r($_GET) it echos an empty array.

Comment: Yes you can get the var with `get_query_var("video_id")` `get_query_var("video_src")` `get_query_var("video_title")`

Comment: can you help me with this topic: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39708/why-is-are-these-rewrite-tags-and-rules-not-working