# help with rewrite_tag and rewrite_rule for custom page GET variables

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, mod-rewrite, rewrite-tag

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [custom htaccess rewrite rule for page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39665/custom-htaccess-rewrite-rule-for-page)

ok i made another post and i got pointed to the Rewrite API

however, when i do print_r($_GET) on the page, it echos an empty array

heres my code in my themes function.php file using the Rewrite API:

```
function add_video_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_tag("%video_id%", '([^/]*)');
    add_rewrite_tag("%video_src%", '([^/]*)');
    add_rewrite_tag("%video_title%", '([^/]*)');
    add_rewrite_rule('^video/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)', 'video/?video_id=$matches[1]&video_src=$matches[2]&video_title=$matches[3]', 'bottom');
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_video_rewrite' );
```

im trying to get this to work for an url like this:

mysite.com/video/102230/MTAyMjMw/FC+Emmen+v+AGOVV+ApeldoornAyMjEx/

but when i visit that URL, my GET variables are coming up empty

it works perfect when i visit this url:

mysite.com/video/?video_id=102230&video_title=FC+Emmen+v+AGOVV+Apeldoorn&video_src=MTAyMjMw

Comment: I gave you an answer to that at that question, no need for a new question I guess. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39665/custom-htaccess-rewrite-rule-for-page/39666#39666

Comment: Please edit your original question with additional details, instead of creating new one.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`get_query_var`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var) rather than `$_GET`. But you will need to register you custom variables, for instance:

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'register_my_query_vars' );
function register_my_query_vars( $qvars ){
    //Add these query variables
    $qvars[] = 'video_id';
    $qvars[] = 'vide_title';
    $qvars[] = 'venue_src';

    return $qvars;
}
```

Then you should be able to use `get_query_var('venue_id')`.

Comment: His queryvars are already set by using `add_rewrite_tag("%video_id%", '([^/]*)');` See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag