# why is are these rewrite_tags and rules not working?

Tags: rewrite-rules, rewrite-tag

im trying to get this to work for 3 different pages

it was working fine with 1 rewrite, then when i added 2 more its not working for any of them.

heres the code:

```
function add_video_rewrite () 
{
    add_rewrite_tag("%video_id%", '([^/]*)');
    add_rewrite_tag("%video_slug%", '([^/]*)');
    add_rewrite_rule('^video/([^/]*)/([^/]*)', 'video/?video_id=$matches[1]&video_slug=$matches[2]', 'bottom');
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_video_rewrite' );

function add_team_rewrite () 
{
    add_rewrite_tag("%team_id%", '([^/]*)');
    add_rewrite_tag("%team_slug%", '([^/]*)');
    add_rewrite_rule('^videos/team/([^/]*)/([^/]*)', 'videos/?team_id=$matches[1]&team_slug=$matches[2]', 'bottom');
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_team_rewrite' );

function add_league_rewrite () 
{
    add_rewrite_tag("%league_id%", '([^/]*)');
    add_rewrite_tag("%league_slug%", '([^/]*)');
    add_rewrite_rule('^videos/league/([^/]*)/([^/]*)', 'videos/?league_id=$matches[1]&league_slug=$matches[2]', 'bottom');
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_league_rewrite' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rewriterules arn't correct anymore. You changed

```
add_rewrite_rule('^video/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/[^/]*)', 'index.php?pagename=video&video_id=$matches[1]&video_src=$matches[2]&video_title=$matches[3]', 'top');
```

To

```
add_rewrite_rule('^video/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/[^/]*)', 'video/&video_id=$matches[1]&video_src=$matches[2]&video_title=$matches[3]', 'bottom');
```

The correct rewriterules for your pages are:
Video

```
add_rewrite_rule('^video/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/[^/]*)', 'index.php?pagename=video&video_id=$matches[1]&video_src=$matches[2]&video_title=$matches[3]', 'top');
```

Team

```
add_rewrite_rule('^videos/team/([^/]*)/([^/]*)', 'index.php?pagename=videos&team_id=$matches[1]&team_slug=$matches[2]', 'top');
```

League

```
add_rewrite_rule('^videos/league/([^/]*)/([^/]*)', 'index.php?pagename=videos&league_id=$matches[1]&league_slug=$matches[2]', 'top');
```

For team and league I assumed your WordPress page is "videos". If it is the subpage then you have to change "pagename=videos" to "pagename=videos/team" and "pagename=videos/league" in your rewriterules.

Comment: i just made your changes and it still shows "Page Not Found" when i try and visit it. yes the pages are called "video" and "videos".

Comment: Did you flush your rewriterules? (go to settings > permalinks)

Comment: flushing fixed it. however on the pages i now get the the error "Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses at offset 29 in /home/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php on line 201"

Comment: I really don't know why this wouldn't work. All page get that error?

Comment: no, just the ones that use the custom rewrite rule.

Comment: Can you test the  rewriterules per page? So comment out the team and league rewriterules, flush your rewriterules and test the video page. Then if that one works (as it should because it did before), you can add another and check again.

Comment: it only worked when i replaced "top" with "bottom", and instead of "?pagename=video" i just used "video/?". thats how i got rid of the error before. but for whatever reason when i tried adding that for the 2 other pages it broke everything.

Comment: i created a new question for this problem: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39721/custom-rewrite-rules-causing-unmatched-parentheses-at-offset-error