# custom url rewrite

Tags: url-rewriting

I have a custom search, one database out of WP, I store the page in wordpress admin panel:

http://localhost/wp/wp-admin/post.php?post=96&action=edit&message=1

Then the page's url looks like `http://localhost/wp/directory/view?search=moto&number=12`

Now I want to modify it into `http://localhost/wp/directory/view/moto/12`. I tried the method with `RewriteRule ^directory/view/(.*)/(\d+)/$ directory/view?search=$2&number=$3`,  and the whole `.htaccess` is:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^directory/view/(.*)/(\d+)/$ directory/view?search=$2&number=$3 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

but it does not work, need a work code, thanks,

EDIT:
I tried `add_rewrite_rule` still not worked... To avoid page name infection, the better way use  `directory/view`.

```
function add_directory_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_tag("%search%", '(.+)');
    add_rewrite_tag("%number%", '(\d+)');
    add_rewrite_rule('^directory/view/(.+)/(\d+)/', 'directory/view?search=$matches[1]&number=$matches[2]', 'top');
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_directory_rewrite' );
```

Comment: This should be handled with WordPress rewrite rules system, not htaccess. see the answer to [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39665/custom-htaccess-rewrite-rule-for-page).

Comment: Could you rephrase? It's not clear what directory/view is, how it's being generated, and what is generating it. Is it a taxonomy? Custom plugin? There's not enough information to answer this question.

Comment: @Tom J Nowell, I creat an empty page `directory` then creat an page `view` which pareant page is `directory`, all this finish in admin panel `add page`. but url rewrite rule not suit for it... Thanks.

Comment: @Milo, I tried it by myself, but still not work...

Comment: @yulichika - all requests in WordPress get routed to index.php, your rewrite rule should point to index.php with `pagename=` set to the page you want to point it to, `directory/view` in this case.

Comment: Why do you add the % around the tags in add_rewrite_tag("%search%", '(.+)');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your rewriterule should be:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^directory/view/(.+)/(\d+)/', 'index.php?pagename=directory/view&search=$matches[1]&number=$matches[2]', 'top');
```

Remember to flush your rewriterules after every edit (go to settings > permalinks).

---

EDIT added complete code example.

```
function add_directory_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_tag("%search%", '(.+)');
    add_rewrite_tag("%number%", '(\d+)');
    add_rewrite_rule('^directory/view/(.+)/(\d+)', 'index.php?pagename=directory/view&search=$matches[1]&number=$matches[2]', 'top');
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_directory_rewrite' );
```

In page.php for testing purposes:

```
<?php echo get_query_var("search"); echo get_query_var("number"); ?>
```

This worked on my own site, even changed the blog url to /blog/ to test the structure.

If this still doesn't work, maybe empty your htaccess an save it in settings > permalinks again (make sure the file is writable).

Removed trailing slash from `'^directory/view/(.+)/(\d+)/'` and it works.

Comment: still some trouble, I checked the `.htaccess` something added:  `RewriteRule ^^directory/view/(.+)/(\d+)/ /wp/?pagename=directory/view?search=$matches[1]&number=$matches[2] [QSA,L]` .by the way, my rewritebase is `RewriteBase /wp/`

Comment: forgot the index.php in the rewriterule. See answer now. Btw I don't know if /wp mathers, but if this won't work change `('^directory/view/` in the rewriterule to `'^wp/directory/view/`  and try again.

Comment: @this time show `404`, If I remove `RewriteRule`, open `http://localhost/wp/directory/view?search=moto&number=12`, I can visit the page. now the `.htaccess` is `RewriteRule ^^directory/view/(.+)/(\d+)/ /wp/index.php?pagename=directory/view?search=$matches[1]&number=$matches[2] [QSA,L]`

Comment: Edited my answer tested in on my own site with "/blog/directory/view?search=test&number=2"

Comment: +1 for your kindly, but still 404 in mine local test. And also test in your page `http://vermeertech.nl/blog/directory/view?search=test&number=2`.

Comment: Ok it is the trailing slash :-) See answer.

Comment: find why your method not worked. `<?php echo get_query_var('pagename'); ?>`, the page name is `view` not `directory/view`, but remove the `directory` still not work. because my rewritebase is `RewriteBase /wp/` not `RewriteBase /wp/directory/`. I have construction my site for a long time, I am not willing to modify my page's base url for too many links should be mofify, it really make me headache...

Comment: Pagename=direcotory/view means you have a page called view with a parent called directory, so this should work. Tried it on a single install, multi install and local in /wp/ folder.

Comment: Your forgetting that directory/view isn't a folder on the server, and there will need to be variables for that too, since directory/view on its own needs rewrite rules to work, so what your rules are doing are the same as if directory/view weren't there at all

Comment: This rewrite rule is only for /directory/view/something/123/ not for /directory/view/. /directory/view/ gets picked up by the general page rewriterule.

Comment: Does not work on my site either