# Facebook sharer and parameters in URL

Tags: facebook, mod-rewrite, sharing

So after a lot of troubles (and thanks to [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/39666)) I managed to make a GET parameter look better in URL, from 
`www.url.com/mypage/?id=123` to `www.url.com/mypage/123/`

I hoped that would solve the redirection problem with Facebook sharer, but it doesn't.
Facebook still recognizes my shared url as `www.url.com/mypage/`

How is it even possible? Studying some Wordpress rewrite rules, I learned that when I type (link1) `www.url.com/nameofpage/` in fact I get redirected to (link2) `www.url.com/?pagename=nameofpage`.

So why when I share link1 it recognizes it without redirecting to link2?
How can I share the link I want (with id parameter) and make it work without redirections?

---

Edit: my code to rewrite the URL

```
add_action( 'init', 'miareg' );
function miareg(){
    add_rewrite_tag("%id%", '(\d+)');
    add_rewrite_rule('^flipbook/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=6031&id=$matches[1]','top');
}
```

The real name of the page I have to share is /flipbook/ and the parameter is "id"; for example I have to share `www.mywebsite.com/flipbook/?id=82`.

To explain `page_id=6031` : it's of course the id of the page (has nothing to do with the id mentioned before - the parameter)

Comment: You are missunderstanding, link1 `www.url.com/nameofpage/` is not redirect to link2 `www.url.com/?pagename=nameofpage`. What is happening is a rewrite, that is quite different of a redirect. The rewrite is a process within you server and no one can see it. Can you post the exact code are you using?

Comment: @cybnet You are right, my mistake. I added the code, can you please check if it's correct? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that you are rewritting to a specific page and I think that your problem is that Wordpress inserts the canonial meta tag in the `<head>` of the HTML automatically for all core post types (post, pages, ...). This meta tag will be pointing to the original page, because you are really in the page 'flipbook'. Maybe facebook is taking the information from the canonial meta tag as Google and the other big search engine will do.

Can you check the canonical meta tag of your pages?

Comment: Yes!!! Just figured it out a minute before you posted it :) It was the tag `<meta property="og:url">` that pointed to the original page (I have SEO Yoast installed).